# How likely is it that rate-of-test-taking impacts on WM tests?

Tags: working-memory

Rate-of-test-taking (also known as r9) is one of the main subsets of processing speed, so is tested via e.g. the symbol digit coding task. I believe it is affected by e.g. depression.

How likely is it that rate-of-test-taking impacts on WM tests, the digit span test etc,?

It was pointed out in [this answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/18329/does-the-digit-span-test-draw-on-any-executive-functions-besides-working-memory/18527?noredirect=1#comment34782_18527) that tests of WM should create a "bottleneck" so that other cognitive processes are implicated less. What about r9?

Answer (score 1):

According to "[The neuroscience of working memory capacity and training](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27225070)" by Christos Constantinidis & Torkel Klingberg asserts that training can increase WM capacity, however this does not translate into better reasoning power:

> Ongoing research  aims to elucidate the extent to which the
>   improvements  also translate to various other abilities, such as
>   academic  abilities, that statistically correlate with WM capacity. 
>   Indeed, transfer to reasoning ability has been reported to  be small,
>   with inconsistent findings.

However, transfers to attention seem more promising:

> More-encouraging  transfer results are seen for attention: several
>   randomized,  controlled trials, some of them including children with 
>   ADHD, show decreases in inattentive behaviour in every-day life after
>   WM training

They cite to support this:

> Klingberg, T. et al.  Computerized training of working  memory in
>   children with ADHD — a randomized,  controlled trial.  J. Am. Acad.
>   Child Adolesc. Psychiatry  44 , 177–186 (2005)
>
> Brehmer, Y., Westerberg, H. & Backman, L. Working- memory training in
>   younger and older adults: training  gains, transfer, and maintenance.
>   Front. Hum. Neurosci.  6 , 63 (2012).
>
> Green, C. T. et al.  Will working memory training  generalize to
>   improve off-task behavior in children with 
>   attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder?  Neurotherapeutics 9 ,
>   639–648 (2012).
>
> Bigorra, A., Garolera, M., Guijarro, S. & Hervas, A.  Long-term
>   far-transfer effects of working memory  training in children with
>   ADHD: a randomized  controlled trial.  Eur. Child Adolesc. Psychiatry
>   http:// dx.doi.org/
>   10.1007/s00787-015-0804-3  (2015).
>
> Conklin, H. M. et al.  Computerized cognitive training  for
>   amelioration of cognitive late effects among  childhood cancer
>   survivors: a randomized controlled  trial.  J. Clin. Oncol.  33 ,
>   3894–3902 (2015)

Comment: that doesn't answer the question though!

Comment: @user3293056 you changed your question after I answered it... If my initial answer didn't answer you initial question, maybe ask a more specific question? But that's just my opinion. It's your question and you can do what you want with it. :)

Comment: ah sorry, i don't recall